# Al intentar correr Nginx en Docker, aparece "pull access denied for ngnix, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'"

Tags: docker, nginx

Tengo este error con Nginx en Docker a la hora de querer correr el contenedor:

`docker container run -d -p 80:80 ngnix`

Me aparece esto:

> Unable to find image 'ngnix:latest' locally 
> docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for ngnix, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.
> See 'docker run --help'.

¿Alguna idea de el porqué? Si corro Nginx desde Docker desktop no marca error, el proceso aparece como activo, pero no puedo interactuar más allá de eso porque me sale ese error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema es que has escrito mal Nginx, en vez de poner nginx has escrito ngnix. Pon el comando de la siguiente forma:

```bash
docker run -d -p 80:80 nginx
```

### Explicación del error

Al haber escrito mal el nombre de la imagen del contenedor, Docker intenta buscarla en local, como no existe (si la tuvieras la usaría), la intenta buscar en los repositorios de Docker y como tampoco existe te dice que puede que no exista o tengas que hacer login a un repositorio privado para descargarla.